# Erro em formulário django

Tags: django

estou tentando rodar um formulario em django mas ele volta esse erro

```
form = TopicoForm() 



raise ValueError('ModelForm has no model class specified.')
```

esse é o meu models

```
class Topico(models.Model):

    titulo = models.CharField('Título', max_length=100)
    mensagem = models.TextField('Mensagem')
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='core/images', verbose_name='Imagem', blank=True, null=True)
    id_usuario = models.ForeignKey(Usuario)
    id_assunto = models.ForeignKey(Assunto)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.titulo
```

o form

```
class TopicoForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class meta:
        model = Topico
        fields = '__all__'
```

e a views

```
def novo_post(request):
    if request.POST:
        form = TopicoForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid:
            form.save()

    else:
        form = TopicoForm()
    contexto = {
        "form": form
    }
    return render(request, "novo_post.html", contexto)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro ocorreu porque você escreveu `meta` em vez de `Meta`, o correto seria:

```
class TopicoForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Topico
        fields = '__all__'
```